# java string toString with condition

Tags: java, string, object, tostring

I have to write a PhonePlan object that will represent the type of plan that a customer has for his/her phone. So the object must keep track of the minutesAllowed (int), minutes used (int), dataAllowed (int), data used (int) and planType (boolean):

```
public class PhonePlan {
     int minutesAllowed;
     int minutesUsed;
     int dataAllowed;
     int dataUsed;
     boolean planType;
}
```

I needed to write a constructor which has minutesAllowed, dataAllowed, and the planType as arguments which I did:

```
public PhonePlan (int ma, int da, boolean pt){
    this.minutesAllowed = ma;
    this.planType = pt;
    this.dataAllowed = da;
}
```

And finally I have to write a string method that displays the plan depending on the type of plan.

I also have to test my code with the following test program;

```
public class PlanTestProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println(new PhonePlan(200, 2500000, false));
        System.out.println(new PhonePlan(250, 500000, true));
        System.out.println(new PhonePlan(300, 5000000, false));
        System.out.println(new PhonePlan(60, 1000000, false));
        System.out.println(new PhonePlan(30, 0, true));
    }
```

The first element being the minutesAllowed, the second one being the amount of dataAllowed and the third one is stating if planType is true of false.

I tried many different things but I am not able to construct a toString() method that take into account if my planType is either true or false...

My Attempt:

```
public String toString(){ 
    return ( "Regular(" + minutesAllowed + " minute," + dataAllowed 
              + "GB data) Monthly Plan with " 
              + getMinutesRemaining() + " minutes remaining and " 
              + getDataRemaining() + "KB remaining"); 
}
```

Comment: What does a boolean planType even mean? Can you share the output you expect for this program?

Comment: What do you want to be print? Not clear...

Comment: Can you share you attempts at implementing the `toString` method and explain why you're not satisfied with them?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).From that second link: "Questions [...] must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: planType is simply a variable @Mureinik

Comment: I meet two way thinkink about toString(), 1. as help, logging, debug info, 2. final formatting for End-User (like this question). Many authors say 2nd is overdesign or bad design

Comment: +1 for the 1st... but I suppose this example is for educational purpose of "toString()" method. Otherwise I found this as language raping, if I may so bold.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement the toString method as described in the following code

```
public class PhonePlan {
int minutesAllowed;
int minutesUsed;
int dataAllowed;
int dataUsed;
boolean planType;
public PhonePlan (int ma, int da, boolean pt){
    this.minutesAllowed = ma;
    this.planType = pt;
    this.dataAllowed = da;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return planType ? getPlanTypeBasedString("Weekly Plan") : getPlanTypeBasedString("Monthly Plan");
}
public String getPlanTypeBasedString(String planType){
    return ( "Regular(" + minutesAllowed + " minute," + dataAllowed
            + "GB data) "+planType+" with "
            + getMinutesRemaining() + " minutes remaining and "
            + getDataRemaining() + "KB remaining");
}
```

Comment: no need of the test `if(planType==true)` just `if(planType)`  would be just fine.

Comment: Also, I'm not the downvoter. Your answer is fine to me.

Comment: I smell too much duplicity there :o... It would be nice to pull those duplicity to intermediate variable.

Comment: What do you propose? @IvoHrádek

Comment: changed a bit and removed redundancy

Comment: @Annie-PierTremblay - Let's give takethefake a chance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily update `return` in your suggested (attempt) `toString` method, by using the **shorthand if/else**, into the following:

```
return ("Regular(" + minutesAllowed + " minute," + dataAllowed 
          + "GB data) " + ((PlanType)? "Monthly": "Annual") + " Plan with " 
          + getMinutesRemaining() + " minutes remaining and " 
          + getDataRemaining() + "KB remaining");
```

Answer (score 0):

Metod `toString()` should never be used to showcase the value of the object properties. For the overrides you can use commons library

```
public String toString() {
 return new ToStringBuilder(this).
   append("minutesAllowed", minutesAllowed).
   append("minutesUsed", minutesUsed).
   append("dataAllowed", dataAllowed).
   append("dataUsed", dataUsed).
   append("planType", planType).
   toString();
}
```